# Autocompletion in Qt Creator is not working

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qt-creator

Autocompletion in my installation of Qt Creator is not longer working. I have "Activate Completion" set to "Always" however it doesn't work, even when I press Control + Space.

It used to work fine though, so I don't know why it suddenly stopped. Does anybody know what could be the reason?

Comment: Do the 'parsing' or 'evaluating' steps (see above run/build button) happen when you change some in your `.pro` file ?

Comment: Yes I see "Evaluating" when I change my .pro file

Comment: For whatever reason `ctrl-space` isn't captured. I can't even record it. Changing the shortcut fixed it for me (v4.2.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found what the issue was. This is because I started using precompiled headers which means many classes are now in stable.h and apparently not found by the editor. I fixed the issue by adding `#include "stable.h"` in all the files, like in VC++.

Comment: This is a [known bug in Qt Creator](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-476) — precompiled headers aren't added to the autocompletion data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .cpp and .h files are not added properly in the command SOURCES and HEADERS of .pro file and the lists need to be aligned to the left with two tabs.